# Text on clickable image when hovering

Tags: html, css, text, hover, clickable

I'm fairly new to HTML en CSS. I'm trying to make a portfoliowebsite. What I want to achieve is: clickable images that show the name of the work (text) when hovering. I hope someone can help. Many thanks.

HTML:

```
<div id="imagelist">
                            <a href="images/tn.png"><img src="images/tn.png" alt="tn" class="hover"/><p class="text">text</p></a>
                            <a href="images/tn.png"><img src="images/tn.png" alt="tn"/></a>
                            <a href="images/tn.png"><img src="images/tn.png" alt="tn"/></a>
                            <a href="images/tn.png"><img src="images/tn.png" alt="tn"/></a>
                            <a href="images/tn.png"><img src="images/tn.png" alt="tn"/></a>
                            <a href="images/tn.png"><img src="images/tn.png" alt="tn"/></a>
                            <a href="images/tn.png"><img src="images/tn.png" alt="tn"/></a>
                            <a href="images/tn.png"><img src="images/tn.png" alt="tn"/></a>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
#imagelist
    {
        float: left;
        font-size: 0px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 0%;
        width: 90%;
    }

#imagelist a
    {
        margin: 10px 20px 10px 0px;
        border: 0px solid transparent;
        display: inline-block;
        border-radius: 1px;
    }

#imagelist a:hover
    {
        border-color: black;
        opacity: 0.5; 
        filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    }

#imagelist .text
    {
        position: relative;
        bottomm: 30px;
        left: 0px;
        visibility: hidden;
    }

#imagelist:hover .text 
    {
        visibility:visible;
        text-color: black;
    }
```

Comment: What goes wrong with what you've tried? I don't see any captions in your code...

Comment: Everytime I try to implement some code for the 'hover text' the images stop being clickable and/or they move to a different place.

Comment: Please edit your question and show us the code you've tried. Maybe we can help find the problem.

Comment: Updated it, still in desperate need of help haha

Comment: Nice, you're not so far off. Just remove `font-size:0` so that your captions are big enough to read and put the hover action on the links rather than the container: `#imagelist a:hover .text`. Not the most spectacular method, but it's simple and it works. [Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/sn96Lc8s/).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy code on bootply:

http://www.bootply.com/90238

It uses bootstraps native features along with this tiny bit of JS

```
    $("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip();    

    $('.thumbnail').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).find('.caption').slideDown(250); //.fadeIn(250)
    },
    function(){
        $(this).find('.caption').slideUp(250); //.fadeOut(205)
    }
    );
```

The images were used from an example created by http://www.bootply.com/users/sevenx

Comment: you can make that in css

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry to bother, but is there a way without JS? It's a project I'm supposed to do in html and css.

Comment: Sure I will write a css version, one sec

Comment: posted as a new answer @Ministar since both answers work and may help someone

Comment: that would be awesome

Answer (score 1):

### is this how you want

```css
a>div { display: none; }
a:hover>div { display: block; }
img{width:100px;height:100px}
```

```html
<a><img src="/you/image" />
<div>Some text</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a CSS-Only version. Added as a new answer since both posts answer the question appropriately.

http://jsfiddle.net/3Pghz/3/

```
#wrapper .text {
position:relative;
bottom:30px;
left:0px;
visibility:hidden;
}

#wrapper:hover .text {
visibility:visible;
}

<div id="wrapper">
<img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" class="hover" />
<p class="text">text</p>
</div>
```